# How to load associations conditionaly in sequlize.js?

Tags: javascript, associations, sequelize.js

```
Post.findAndCountAll({
  include: [{
    model: models.like,
    where: { userId: req.authSession.user.id } 
  ]}
}).then( collection => {
  onSucess(collection);
});
```

This will load posts if they have an associated like from the user. However what I want is loading all the user's post and loading the associated like if its exist. Can I archive this behaviour somehow with sequlize.js?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to nest the `where` clause one level above.

```
Post.findAndCountAll({
  where: { userId: req.authSession.user.id },
  include: [{model: models.like}]
}).then( collection => {
  onSucess(collection);
});
```

This will return all Posts that have `userId === req.authSession.user.id` and will include their likes ( if any ).

**Edit according to the comment**

If you want to have the Likes of the user you can just revert the query

```
Like.findAndCountAll({ 
    where: { userId: req.authSession.user.id },
    include: [ { model: models.post } ]
});
```

Comment: Yes but I only want the like of the given user, the full request I use was truncated when I posted it here. in real life it already has the outer where method. But this returns all the likes what will be a huge list over time, I only want the one like of the authenticated user if there is one l.

Comment: Thanks, but still not good. I dont want the likes of the user. I want posts, and the like of the user if he liked the given post. So the stucture should be something like `[{postId, etc, like: null},[{postId, etc, like: LikeObject},[{postId, etc, like: LikeObject},[{postId, etc, like: null}]` so I want to query the posts, get them independently from the existence of a like or not, but if a like exist from the logged in user, then I want to include that as well. Let me know if its not clear, then I will update my question in detail.